# How to format this namespace list into a structured object with no duplicates?

Tags: c#, data-structures

So I have a list of objects that contain this namespace property. What I am trying to do is group the list into an object that contains no duplicates and is structured like this:

```
Core
   Util
      Log
      Fetch
   Math
      Add
      Subtract
```

The input list would look like this:

```
[
  {
    Namespace: "Core.Util",
    Name: "Log"
  },
  {
    Namespace: "Core.Util",
    Name: "Fetch"
  },
  {
    Namespace: "Core.Math",
    Name: "Add"
  },
  {
    Namespace: "Core.Math",
    Name: "Subtract"
  }
]
```

Comment: yep, the top is what I want, the bottom is the data provided. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: You want something like this?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/dvibPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to convert a flat list of objects into a recursive hierarchy of nodes, where each node is specified by some unique name within the context of its parent.  You've tagged your question [data-structures](/questions/tagged/data-structures) so you are looking for a data model that will make it easy to construct such a hierarchy.

Generalizing a bit, each node then should look like the following:

```
public abstract partial class HierarchicalNode<TItem, THierarchicalNode>
    where THierarchicalNode : HierarchicalNode<TItem, THierarchicalNode>, new()
{
    public IDictionary<string, THierarchicalNode> Children { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<TItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public HierarchicalNode()
    {
        this.Children = new Dictionary<string, THierarchicalNode>();
        this.Items = new List<TItem>();
    }
}
```

Here the node contains:

1. A list of objects, of type `TItem`.  (You would be using `string` for this.)
2. A dictionary of child nodes of the same type.  Here we use a dictionary to guarantee that there are no duplicates in the namespace names.
3. I defined `Items` to be a list, but if you need to prevent duplication of items as well, you could replace the concrete implementation with a `HashSet<TItem>`

You'll also need some recursive logic to construct the hierarchy.  The following should do the trick:

```
public partial class HierarchicalNode<TItem, THierarchicalNode>
{
    public THierarchicalNode GetOrAddChild(string namespaceName)
    {
        THierarchicalNode child;
        if (!Children.TryGetValue(namespaceName, out child))
            child = Children[namespaceName] = new THierarchicalNode();
        return child;
    }

    public void AddObject(IList<string> nodeNames, TItem item)
    {
        AddObject(nodeNames, 0, item);
    }

    void AddObject(IList<string> nodeNames, int index, TItem item)
    {
        if (index >= nodeNames.Count)
            Items.Add(item);
        else
        {
            GetOrAddChild(nodeNames[index]).AddObject(nodeNames, index + 1, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the relevant method is `AddObject(IList<string> nodeNames, TItem item)` which adds an object that lives inside a nested list of nodes, specified by the list of names.

Finally, since you are interested in namespaces, you would define your specific type as follows:

```
public class Namespace : HierarchicalNode<string, Namespace>
{
}
```

And construct a root `Namespace` as follows:

```
// Deserialize the JSON shown in the question to an array of objects with Namespace and Name properties
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(
    jsonString, 
    new[] { new { Namespace = default(string), Name = default(string) } });

var root = new Namespace();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    // Split the Namespace property into an array for recursive processing
    root.AddObject(item.Namespace.Split('.'), item.Name);
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dvibPE).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are parsing the JSON using JSON.Net into objects, you can use Linq to group them by their "Namespace" property:

```
 var results = jsonObjects.GroupBy(o => new { Core = o.Namespace.Split('.')[0], Sub = o.Namespace.Split('.')[1] });
```

This would give you 2 groups (Core.Util and Core.Math) with 2 entries each.
I don't know what you mean by "no duplicates" exactly, but I suggest you take a look at the LINQ Distinct()-operator.